# perl: extract substring enclosed between specific strings

Tags: perl, operators, substring

(Looked at other similar questions and answers and got intimidated - and thus ask your forgiveness if this is a redundant and/or too simple of a question.)

Need to extract a substring enclosed by operators, say, `<begin>` and `<end>`.

Example:

```
Irrelevant text is here <begin>the substring I am looking for<end> other irrelevant text
```

For the sake of simplicity, I need only the first match if there are several.

P.S. The string I am extracting is time in the form of `23:59:59;00` which I need then to compare to system time and generate an alert if there is a mismatch by more than a minute, accounting for end of day (e.g. the above time is close enough to `00:00:15;45` and should not be an exception. But that should be a separate question, I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $text = "Irrelevant text is here <begin>the substring I am looking for<end> other irrelevant text";

my ($string) = $text =~ /<begin>(.*?)<end>/ or warn "Pattern did not match";
```

Comment: thank you! (can't "vote up" regretfully - not enough reputation)

Answer (score 1):

```
my $text = "Irrelevant text is here <begin>the substring I am looking for<end> other irrelevant text";

my $string = $& if $text =~ /<begin>\K.*?(?=<end>)/;
```